# Alternating series: Does $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{e^{\ln(n)}}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

To be specific I need to determine whether the series absolutely converges or conditionally converges.
I have already determined if the series converges and diverges (it converges) through the Alternating Series Test. However, I cannot determine whether it absolutely or conditionally converges. I've tried the Ratio Test and Root Test, both of which results to 1.
Ratio Test

> $\lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = \lim_{n \to \infty} | (\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{e^{\ln(n+1)}}) \cdot {\frac{e^{\ln(n)}}{(-1)^n}} |$
> $= \lim_{n \to \infty} |-1| e^{ \ln(\frac{n}{n+1}) } = e^{ \lim_{n \to \infty} \ln(\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n}}) } $
> $= e^{ \ln(1) } = 1$

Root Test

> $\lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} |(-1)^n| (\frac{1}{e^{\ln(n)}})^{\frac{1}{n}}$
> $= \lim_{n \to \infty} (e^{ \frac{-\ln(n)}{n} }) = e^{ -\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n} }  $
> $= e^{ -\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} }  = 1$

And as far as I know, $\lim_{x \to \infty} a_n = 1$, does not necessarily mean anything.
Are there any more test aside from ratio and root test to determine whether a series absolutely converges or not? Or did I do something wrong when solving for the limit on the Ratio and/or Root Test?

Comment: Before you do anything, $e^{\ln n} =n$. Then it’s apparent that it converges conditionally.

Comment: Per the other responses: [1] $1 + (1/2) + (1/3) + \cdots$ is know to be divergent.  [2] Per the [Alternating Series Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) the series is conditionally convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $e^{\ln(n)}=n$ for all $n$. Thus

$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{e^{\ln(n)}}=\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}.$$

Alternating harmonic series !

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{e^{\ln(n)}}=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}=-\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}-1\right)=1-\ln(2)$$